# cleveref and lineno

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, lineno

How can I get `cleveref` to work with `\linelabel` from `lineno`?

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{cleveref}



\begin{document}
\linenumbers

Bla bla bla  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \linelabel{foo}  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

\cref{foo} doesn't work because the cleveref line doesn't get written to the aux file, but \ref{foo} works.
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\linelabel` is not using `\label` and that's why `cleveref` can't hook into it

Comment: I understand why it goes wrong.  What I want to know is how to fix it.  In other words, how can I tweak `\linelabel` to write a cleveref-compatible line to the aux file?

Comment: One possibility is to use `\cref@currentlabel`, but I have no time to figure it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a quick hack, using `\@LN@linelabel` which does the line labelling.

First I use the old version of the command, extract the label value again, then set a backup counter, set `linenumber` to the label value, decrease it and step it again to get the correct `\cref@currentlabel` and then write label directly as `cleveref` would do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}


\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcounter{backuplineno}

\crefname{linenumber}{linenumber}{linenumbers}
\Crefname{linenumber}{Linenumber}{Linenumbers}



\makeatletter
\let\@LN@linelabelorig\@LN@linelabel
\renewcommand{\@LN@linelabel}[1]{%
  \@LN@linelabelorig{#1}%
  \IfRefUndefinedExpandable{#1}{}{%
    \setcounter{backuplineno}{\value{linenumber}}
    \addtocounter{linenumber}{-1}%
    \setcounter{linenumber}{\numexpr\getrefnumber{#1} -1}
    \refstepcounter{linenumber}%
    \protected@write\@auxout{}%
    {\string\newlabel{#1@cref}{{\cref@currentlabel}{\thepage}}}%
    \setcounter{linenumber}{\value{backuplineno}}
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\linenumbers

Bla bla bla  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \linelabel{foo}  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

\cref{foo} doesn't work because the cleveref line doesn't get written to the aux file, but \ref{foo} works.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll try to find a better version